# Premultiplied coeficcient in a regression

Tags: regression

I have a data generating process (DGP) of the following form:

$
y = \beta_r f(x_r) \times (\beta_1 \times x_1 + \ldots + \beta_n \times x_n)
$

The DGP reflects some factor loadings ($x_1 \ldots x_n$) and their coefficients $\beta$ that are scaled by some function $f(x_r)$.

I would like to estimate the coefficients with, say, a linear regression model. My first impression is that this is not possible since all I can observe is the term $\beta_r f(x_r) \times \beta_n \times x_n$ and thus the coefficients cannot be separated. However, I am not sure if I am overlooking a transformation that allows me to separate the effects.

So here's is my question: Can $\beta_r$ and $\beta_{1\ldots n}$ be separeted and estimated by regression?

**Update:**
To put my question in context: the linear part reflects implicit prices subject to certain specifications ($x_1 \ldots x_n)$. The multiplicative part is a rebate that is granted depending on $x_r$. Therefore $y$ reflects the price for a product net of rebates.